# Обобщенные методы доступа свойств

Tags: c#, .net

**Вот что пишет Рихтер:**

[image: Вот что пишет Рихтер]

Я понял это так:

```
public class ClassB<T> 
{
    private T m_field;
    public T Field
    {
        get {
            return m_field;

        }
        set {
            m_field = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Но такой код работает.
Что тогда в этом абзаце имелось ввиду?

Comment: Имелось ввиду `get<T>{ }` и `set<T>{ }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В приведенном коде, в свойстве `Field` используется тип `T` указанный в классе `ClassB<T>`.

В тексте же речь шла про *собственный параметр типа*:

```
public class ClassB<T> 
{
    private T m_field;
    public U Field<U>
    {
        get {
            return default(U);
        }
    }
}
```

И в этом случае компилятор выдаст ошибку:

> CS7002: Unexpected use of a generic name

> CS7002: Неожиданное использование универсального имени